# value not defined when access php with get method from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, get

I want to send value with get method to my php file.
if i set my url like this

```
http://example.com?id=13
```

it can run normally, but when my id is like this

```
http://example.com?id=a0013
```

a get error in my console log a0013 is not defined. This is my code

```
<?php
//set $id value
$id=a001;
?>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function init(){
     ja = new google.maps.Data();
     ja.loadGeoJson('example.php?id='+<?php echo $id; ?>+'');
}
</script>
```

my example.php

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
//another action
?>
```

Comment: Show your actual code

Comment: _a0013 is not defined_? It should be _id is not defined_, a0013 is the value... isn't it?

Comment: And how is `php` connected with `console.log`?

Comment: sorry i forgot to say, i access the php file from my javascript

Comment: Again, _show your code_.

Comment: After code added - edit to my answer at bottom

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing PHP and JavaScript;
PHP is a server side scripting language
JavaScript is a client side scripting language

The console you mention, is through a browsers inspector tool, and runs off of JavaScript.
If you want to get a request param from this, you could do the following;

```
// Remove the "?" from the URL and split this down by the ampersand
var requestParams = window.location.search.replace("?", "").split("&");
for (var i in requestParams)
{
    // For each of the request parts, split this by the = to het key and value
    // the console log them to display
    var _params = requestParams[i].split("=");
    console.log("Request Param; " + _params[0] + " = " + _params[1])
}
```

This will output something such as;

```
Request Param; id = a0013
```

You can also use these in PHP;

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    print "Request Param; {$key} = {$value}<br />";
}
```

Which will result in the same thing. If you wanted just the a0013 value; using;

```
print $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Will give you this.
Trying to target via the a0013 won't work as that is the value in the data, not the key

**NB** - I use $_REQUEST in this, there is also $_GET (what you see in the URL bar and what JavaScript has access to via window.location.search) and $_POST which is hidden from the user

**FOLLOWING OP EDIT**
Add quote marks around your `$id=a001;` to make it `$id='a001';`

The reason it works with 13 and not a0013 (or a001) is because 13 is an integer and does not need quotes, because the latter has a string (starts with "a") it **MUST** have quotes around it (single or double, doesn't matter)

Comment: sorry i forgot to say, i access the php file from my javascript

Comment: How do you access the PHP from JavaScript? AJAX? I had assumed this was impossible as PHP runs before load (i.e. on server) and JS on/after (i.e. on client) unless you are using AJAX

Comment: @ikhwanaja - we're stabbing in the dark here without seeing what you're doing

Comment: i have a php file. normal php files that have html tags are also in it. I set the onload event in the body tag to call a function in javascript. And in that function I call another php file to get the data.

Comment: @ikhwanaja - we need to see it, we can stab wildly at things 500 miles away, doesn't mean we're gonna hit, we need it to be close, give us something to work with or delete the question, you're not gonna get a viable answer if we can't see what's broken